# Export and Import Outlook 365 Emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

**Export and Import Outlook 365 Emails**

If I have a conversation of more than 35 messages in the same thread and I want to forward it to another user (i.e. not the whole thread, just those 35 messages) or in to `PST` or `OST` file (correct me If I was wrong or suggest the extension file name).

I want the other user to be able to click on the file and view that conversation. I can say my view using the file and not by the whole thread in my messages. Is it possible in outlook 365 2014 (outlook web access 2014).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Clean Up Conversation feature in Outlook 2013 to clean up the entire conversation. The feature will take multiple e-mails and condense them into a single e-mail. For the Clean Up Conversation to work, the e-mails can not be forwarded, responded to with different e-mail addresses (e-mails removed, e-mails added, etc). You can then File > Save As > Msg (Outlook message) file.

If you select multiple e-mails, you can File > Save As > Text instead. You can clean up the text file and remove the redundant portions manually.